# Can the bananas of this variety be eaten?

Tags: plant-care, banana

I recently purchased this banana tree in a flower pot. I've attached two photos with its label. Do you know if the bananas of this variety can be eaten? (Does the "\" icon over the fork and knife mean that they can't be eaten?)

Moreover, should I have it in full sun, or is it OK if it's in shade? Finally, how often should it be watered?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your questions are answered by the icons you posted a picture of.

The crossed out knife-and-fork icon suggests that you cannot eat it. (The circle with the diagonal line mimics the 'prohibited' sign, which can also be found in traffic signs or 'smoking prohibited' stickers.)

The Musa Nana (dwarf banana) is a often used as a synonym for Musa Acuminata. It should be edible (at least not poisonous), but some sources say it contains many seeds, so maybe that's why they regard it as inedible. It could also be that they've treated it with pesticides in such a way that the fruits of this specific specimen should not be eaten. I wouldn't know why else they put that icon up there, because under normal circumstances you could eat these fruits. Or maybe the icon applies to the plant in general, rather than the fruits.

About the sunlight, the plant can (as the icons also suggest) be grown in full sunlight or half-shadow and it should be watered every 5 to 7 days. Bananas use quite a lot of water, so be sure to check if they are not too dry. You should fertize them once a month, even in winters, and in summer you might even want to fertilize more often.

See also:

- http://www.backyardnature.net/yucatan/dwarfban.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_Cavendish_banana

Comment: I thought Musa Nana was a generic term for all dwarf bananas?